# Trying to insert a stored procedure into a temporary table, getting 'an object or column name is missing or empty'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to SELECT * INTO [temp table] FROM [Stored Procedure]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

I am new to [T-SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL). I have a [stored procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) that selects records. I want to query the records returned by the stored procedure, so I am trying to insert the records into a temporary table. (Stack Overflow posts and other posts say that is how to do it.)

But when I try, I get the error:

> object or column name is missing or empty'

When I just run the stored procedure, I get a table that has columns with names.

```
select * into #temp1
exec alexander.dbo.get_uberrecords '20120101', '20120201', 'labcorp' //throws error saying columns must have names
```

but

```
exec alexander.dbo.get_uberrecords '20120101', '20120201', 'labcorp' // Returns cols with names
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try creating the temp table first:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1
(
   COL1 INT,
   COL2 VARCHAR(MAX)   
)

INSERT INTO #temp1 
exec alexander.dbo.get_uberrecords '20120101', '20120201', 'labcorp'
```

In your case of an extremely wide result set, you may want to use `OPENROWSET`

In any case, this SO has many options:
[Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

Comment: @Jeff--unfortunately it is a huge 40 col table, so that is not a great option